# Update an dynamic image that will only update the selected data

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

I'm having difficulting on what problem my code is facing. instead of just updating the record that i am supposed to code for example i am just going to update the image for my "Google tour package" instead of just updating the image of it, it updates all the record , so what happened is all the image in my db is all the same. i think the problem is on  the where clause.

This is windows server running sql and apache in xammp v3.2.2

```
  $targetDir = "../../../../../../img/itinerary/";
  $fileName = basename($_FILES["itinerary_img"]["name"]);
  $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
  $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $itinerary_id = $_GET['id'];

    if(!empty($_FILES["itinerary_img"]["name"]))
    {
        $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes))
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["itinerary_img"]["tmp_name"], 
            $targetFilePath))
            {
                // Insert image file name into database
                $insert ="UPDATE 'tms_itinerary' SET itinerary_img =    ".$fileName."' WHERE itinerary_id = '".$itinerary_id."' ";

               $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $insert);

                if($result2){
                    $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
                }else{
                    $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
                }
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }else{
            $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
        }
    }else{
       $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
    }
```

i expect the output to only change the image of the one i am updating and not all of the itinerary_image

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Echo your `$insert` variable and check what the SQL query looks like. As far as I can see, only records with the same `itinerary_id` would be updated. Are those unique or does all records have the same `itinerary_id`?

Comment: itinerary_id is my unique

Comment: all records have different itinerary_id. they are itinerary are displayed dynamically

Comment: So, did you echo the query to see what it actually looks like? There isn't anything obvious in your code that suggests that it should update all records. You can also remove the single quotes around your table name in your query. But like I mentioned, you should start by rewriting your query to use prepared statements. Otherwise, you're just debugging code you still need to rewrite.